# How can I set a default width for my VS Code Extension webview?

Tags: visual-studio-code, webview, vscode-extensions

I am developing a VS Code extension using a webview. I would like to set the width of the panel when the user first opens it.

I see that there are options for where to place the panel with `ViewColumn` but I have not been able to figure out how to change the default width. Specifically, I would like the panel to open to the right and for the width to be the smallest possible width, basically what I can achieve by manually dragging the split line as far to the right as VS Code will let me. Where can I specify the width?

```ts
const panel = vscode.window.createWebviewPanel(
  'catCoding',
  'Cat Coding',
  vscode.ViewColumn.Two,
  {
    enableScripts: true
  }
);
```

Comment: So, the question is not about a default with for a WebView (which always fills its container), but how to set a with of a view column programmatically.

Comment: @MikeLischke is that something you would be able to explain how to do? I thought maybe I would need to programmatically change a setting for the VS Code workspace or the active editor where my webview is displayed.

Comment: I did some digging and couldn't find any way of doing this, not sure it's possible

Comment: If I knew an answer to that, I would have posted it :-)